# Pass Quasar component name to Vue 3 render function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm trying to dynamically create a Vue 3 app with a component given by name, e.g. "div", "button" or Quasar's "q-btn". But I struggle to pass the latter to Vue's render function `Vue.h`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.10.0/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.10.0/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
    <script>
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        render: () => Vue.h("q-btn", { color: "blue" }, "Click me"),
      });
      app.use(Quasar);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd expect Vue to translate `q-btn` into a `<button>` tag. But instead the resulting HTML contains `<q-btn>` tags which are not correctly rendered by the browser.

When replacing `"q-btn"` with `Quasar.QBtn`, it works as expected. But shouldn't Vue know how to render "q-btn", after Quasar has been installed with `app.use(Quasar)`?

I could find some hacky solution to handle Quasar components, but there will be other libraries as well as custom components and I hope there is a more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I found the answer using [`Vue.resolveComponent`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#resolvecomponent):

```html
render: () => Vue.h(Vue.resolveComponent("q-btn"), { color: "blue" }, "Click me"),
```

Now the Quasar button is rendered correctly.